# Full-width print() causes newline issues

Tags: python, terminal

I'm designing a Python terminal program. I use `os.get_terminal_size()` to get the dimensions of the terminal. However, `print()` appends `\n` and so it seems that the newline character gets pushed on to a new line i.e. I think a new line is added by Python and then *another* newline is added due to terminal text-wrapping *that* newline, causing an unwanted large space. See below:

*The outer `----------` are the borders of the terminal window, and the `----------` under "Welcome" is the printed separator.*

**Expected**

```
+-------------------+
|      Welcome      |
|-------------------|
|Expected output    |
+-------------------+
```

**Actual**

```
+-------------------+
|      Welcome      |
|                   |
|-------------------|
|                   |
|Expected output    |
+-------------------+
```

**Code**:

```py
import os

terminal_dimensions = os.get_terminal_size()

WIDTH = terminal_dimensions[0]
HEIGHT= terminal_dimensions[1]

def center_print(txt):
    print(txt.center(WIDTH))

def print_separator():
    print('-' * WIDTH)
```

Is there a clean way to fix this? I didn't want to use `end=""` because if the user increases terminal width, the two lines are on the same line; it's just an illusion. I want a newline, just not like this, where a new line is added by Python and then *another* newline is added due to terminal text-wrapping that newline.

Comment: Couldn't you just subtract one from the width: i.e. `WIDTH = terminal_dimensions[0]-1`?

Comment: This looks to me like a terminal specific problem, as on `cmd.exe` it produces this behaviour on my machine, but in `wt.exe` (the new Windows Terminal) it doesn't give the extra newline.

Comment: @martineau That wouldn't work for all terminals (see my comment above)

Comment: I'm not sure there's a solution for this. You need a way to tell the terminal to go to a new line, but not add a blank line if you're already at the end of the line. There's no standard control character for this.

Comment: @megargayu: That may be true, but subtracting one would still be OK (i.e. just in case).

Comment: @martineau Oh, right, because its better to have semi-center than an extra newline - and this seems to be working (subtracting one from the terminal width).

Comment: @martineau You should post an answer (or I can do it for you)

Comment: You have the order backwards.  The first newline comes from the terminal wrapping the long line, the second one is the one you send.  The only way around it is to stop sending yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra newline isn't occurring because the newline added by `print` is overflowing, it happens before that.  If you print exactly as many characters as the width of your window, then pause for a while without printing anything else, you'll see that the cursor already wrapped to the next line.  It happens as soon as the current line fills up.

The only way around it is to detect when this happens and avoid adding an extra newline.

```
def myprint(s):
    ending = '\n' if (len(s) % WIDTH) else ''
    print(s, end=ending)
```

Comment: This seems like one of the most viable solutions, even if two adjacent lines will be on the same line if the screen is enlarged

Comment: @Harith I don't think I've ever seen a terminal window that tracks where the newlines are so it can reflow the text when you resize.  If it's smart enough to do that, it should be smart enough to ignore the redundant newlines too.  What are you using?

Comment: CMD.exe 2019 version I think? I think I have the setting "wrap text output on resize" on, from the properties menu. I'll see if it works in Git Bash or the new Windows Terminal, but I am still open for any ideas to work regardless of terminal (maybe me changing CMD settings is more my fault than the programs and I can just add a disclaimer for users to turn that off before using).

Answer (score 0):

A crude but simple way to do it would be to simply subtract one from the `WIDTH` value:

```
import os

terminal_dimensions = os.get_terminal_size()

WIDTH = terminal_dimensions[0]
HEIGHT = terminal_dimensions[1]

def center_print(txt):
    print(txt.center(WIDTH-1))

def print_separator():
    print('-' * (WIDTH-1))

center_print('Welcome')
print_separator()
print('Expected output')
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be the cmd windows problem, `get_terminal_size()`, consider this picking the terminal size as an array, however the size will be +1 usually consider this as 0-n, so it has one more value than what you expect, thus for this situation, CMD will boost one more space to for the remain output, the extra "-".
-1 both `WIDTH` and `HELIGH`will get what you need.